# how to stop email of order programmatically in custom payment method?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.0

```
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement;
...

// Create order from quote

$order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);

// This code send mail automatically

//also used **$order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false);** 

// But this not working in magento 2.3.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Overwrite/pluginize following class which is responsible for sending order mail.

**vendor/magento/module-quote/Observer/SubmitObserver.php**

You can try the following using plugin:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Observer\SubmitObserver">
        <plugin name="SR_MagentoCommunity::stop_sending_order_email_for_custom_payment"
                type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Quote\Observer\SubmitObserver" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Quote/Observer/SubmitObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Quote\Observer;

class SubmitObserver
{
    public function beforeExecute(
        \Magento\Quote\Observer\SubmitObserver $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        /** @var  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        // Add your custom logic here
        $order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false);
        return [$observer];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello brother, I have tried your solution with some payment and order status condition but order mail is still running in that payment cases:  
         if($paymentCode == 'swed_m2s' || $paymentCode == 'seb_m2s' || $paymentCode == 'lhv_m2s' || $paymentCode == 'estcard_m2s' || $paymentCode == 'coop_m2s')
            {
             
                if($orderStatus == 'pending')
                {
                     $order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false);
                }
            }
       
        return [$observer];